# No current assignment for partition: <topic-partition> during re-joining; adding new partitions during run-time doesnt work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have a streaming application that uses [Kafka+SparkStreaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html). I start with one partition, one consumer instance, three brokers.
I want to do following two things in sequence:

1) Add new partitions to a topic during runtime, which I do using:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 192.168.101.164:2181 --alter --topic topic10 --partitions 2
```

2) Add new consumer instances to a particular consumer group which I do by running the same consumer code as a separate process.

However, on doing 1:  I do not see the (only) consumer instance consuming the newly added partition. It only consumes the partitions which it was initially assigned automatically by the zookeeper.

On doing 2: a)The new instance is automatically assigned one partition `topic10-1` which happens successfully but b)The first instance rejoins after rebalancing but fails with the following error inspite of a)

```
17/06/07 16:47:02 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: Revoking previously assigned partitions [topic10-0] for group SparkConsumerGrp
17/06/07 16:47:02 INFO AbstractCoordinator: (Re-)joining group SparkConsumerGrp
17/06/07 16:47:02 INFO AbstractCoordinator: Successfully joined group SparkConsumerGrp with generation 17
17/06/07 16:47:02 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: Setting newly assigned partitions [topic10-0] for group SparkConsumerGrp
17/06/07 16:47:02 ERROR JobScheduler: Error generating jobs for time 1496879222000 ms
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition topic10-1
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.needOffsetReset(SubscriptionState.java:336)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(KafkaConsumer.java:1236)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(DStream.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(DStream.scala:899)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2.apply(DStream.scala:899)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$2.apply(DStream.scala:877)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.slice(DStream.scala:877)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$1.apply(DStream.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$slice$1.apply(DStream.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.slice(DStream.scala:870)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.WindowedDStream.compute(WindowedDStream.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

I notice that the time at which the new instance successfully joins the group exactly matches the time that the first one fails every time.
I am using `Kafka version 0.10.0, Kafka-client version 0.10.0.1, spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11 version 2.1.1`.

Finally, here's the consumer code:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new  SparkConf().setMaster("local[5]").setAppName("SparkConsumer1").set("spark.driver.host", "localhost");

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    // Create a StreamingContext with a 1 second batch size
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(15));    
    List<String> topicSet = Arrays.asList(topics.split(","));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers);
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "SparkConsumerGrp3");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "192.168.101.164:2181");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    kafkaParams.put("session.timeout.ms","30000");

    final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages =
              KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                jssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferBrokers(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topicSet, kafkaParams)
              );
```

I also found something similar [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19547), but there was no real answer. I would really really appreciate any help. Thanks.

**Update**
For 1) I  was able to have the consumer fetch data from newly added partitions. We can configure how often we want the metadata to be refreshed using `metadata.max.age.ms` which is set to `300000` by default.

Comment: Did u get a solution for this?